# MySQL/MariaDB find one or more numbers in list, matching lottery numbers with past results

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB table with an archive of past lottery results, imagine EuroMillions or Powerball lotteries.

For example on EuroMillions numbers go from 1 to 50 and then the extra balls from 1 to 12, each result is 5 numbers form the main pool and 2 from the extra pool. So my historic results table could look like this:

Lottery Results table

```
(other columns like id, date, draw number, etc) | main_numbers | extra_numbers | (timestamp columns)
... | 1,2,3,4,5 | 1,2 | ...
... | 3,12,34,35,45 | 5,11 | ...
... | 4,15,34,39,45 | 10,11 | ...
... | 7,11,25,28,44 | 10,12 | ...
(you get the idea, I have thousands of records...)
```

So I could select main_numbers and get result "`3,12,34,35,45`" for that second example row. And for the extra_numbers I would get "`5,11`".

What I want is to given a set of numbers for main and extra to see if they match any of my results, finding any number of numbers (numbered lottery balls).

So for example if I SELECT to find main_numbers "`5,9,22,34,45`" with extra_numbers "`2,11`" I would get (from my extracted example) two records:

```
... | 3,12,34,35,45 | 5,11 | ...
... | 4,15,34,39,45 | 10,11 | ...
```

Matching two main numbers and one extra number, in this case finding lottery prizes in the results table. Makes sense?

I'm using MariaDB and I'm a bit lost on how to proceed, I tried `WHERE` `IN`, `FIELD_IN_SET`, etc.
Is there a way to perform a `SELECT` to find results in only one statement or do I have to pick all records and then iterate elsewhere, php for example?

My aim would be to have it in one statement, so I could just send the numbers and get the matching records... Possible?

I hope this makes sense.
Many thanks for your answers.

Comment: At a quick glance, you should probably _not_ be storing CSV in your tables like this.  Read about _normalization_ in SQL.

Comment: This is good if you're looking for exact matches across all numbers (i.e. 'jackpots') but not  so useful for partial matches and other types of analysis (frequency, etc.)

Comment: This would actually be quite easy in Postgres using an integer array (can even be indexed)

Comment: I never used Postgres before. I used Mysql, MongoDB and MariaDB...

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

For simplicity, let's say that a lottery comprises 3 main balls, and two bonus balls:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lottery_results;

CREATE TABLE lottery_results
(draw_id INT NOT NULL
,ball_no INT NOT NULL
,ball_val INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(draw_id,ball_no)
);

INSERT INTO lottery_results VALUES
(1,1,22),
(1,2,35),
(1,3,62),
(1,4,27),
(1,5,17),
(2,1,18),
(2,2,33),
(2,3,49),
(2,4, 4),
(2,5,35);
```

And we want to find all results where 34, 35, or 36 were drawn as a main number...

```
SELECT draw_id
  FROM lottery_results 
 WHERE ball_no <=3 
   AND ball_val IN(34,35,36);

+---------+
| draw_id |
+---------+
|       1 |
+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Strawberry,

I found a solution if I have all numbers in distinct columns, but could I find if they are in the same column in CSV?

So if I put my CSV in distinct columns for numbers (n_1...n_5) and extra numbers for the stars in (s_1, s_2) I can seek matched in those multiple columns.

This is using multiple columns:
To find matches numbers 1,2,3,4,5 with stars 1,2...
In EuroMillions you get a prize with 2 or more numbers and any star (one or two).

```
SELECT 
main_numbers, extra_numbers, 
((n_1 IN (1,2,3,4,5)) +
(n_2 IN (1,2,3,4,5)) +
(n_3 IN (1,2,3,4,5)) +
(n_4 IN (1,2,3,4,5)) +
(n_5 IN (1,2,3,4,5))) AS matched_numbers,
((s_1 IN (1,2)) +
(s_2 IN (1,2))) AS matched_stars,
created_at
FROM `lottery_results_archive`
HAVING matched_numbers >= 3 OR matched_numbers = 2 AND matched_stars > 0
ORDER BY matched_numbers DESC, matched_stars DESC, created_at DESC
```

Makes sense?

Thanks.